# Python - How to ensure all lengths of elements in a nested list are the same?

Tags: python

I have a function here:

```
def evenlengthchecker(nestedlist):
    length = len(nestedlist[0])
    for element in nestedlist:
         if len(element) != length:
             return False
```

This actually does work when the given nested list contains values. However, when I try something like `evenlengthchecker([])`, `IndexError`s everywhere!

Comment: Check to see if the array is empty then return if not. You're checking an index that doesn't exist

Comment: Is this your actual code? I'd be surprised if `length = len(nestedlist(0))` runs, because you can't usually call a list that way. Normally you'd get `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`.

Comment: @Sterling Archer Are there any other cases that would cause an error if I add that on? I was thinking of doing that but it would ruin me if there were to be another case.

Comment: @Kevin yeah it's supposed to be `nestedlist[0]`, fixed.

Comment: Ok, but that doesn't really answer my question. Is this 100% identical to the code that's giving you an IndexError? If your original code has a problem that this code doesn't have, then we'll all be on a wild goose chase.

Comment: But the source of the problem in _this_ code is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def evenlengthchecker(nestedlist):
    a = [len(i) for i in nestedlist]
    return len(set(a)) ==1
```

Comment: This may not be most efficient but it is kind of cleanest solution on my mind.

Comment: This will incorrectly return `False` for the empty list.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your code starts by checking the list at position 0, which is an index error with an empty list. Here's an alternative method that won't give an error:

```
return (len(set(len(elt) for elt in nestedlist)) <= 1)
```

This just checks if there is more than one list length in the set of lengths; if you end up with the empty set, no harm done.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `all`:

```
return all(len(x)==len(my_list[0]) for x in my_list)
```